# Why does this calculation return this result? (Python)

Tags: python, math, int

```
return 25.0 * (1 + 16.0/100)
```

this returns `29.0`.
But, when using int() like below,

```
return int(25.0 * (1 + 16.0/100))
```

this returns `28`

I don't understand why it is 28 instead of 29.

Answer (score 3):

The actual result is something like `28.99999999999` which Python rounds to `29.0` for display. However, when converting to an `int`, the digits after the decimal are simply chopped off, leaving you with `28`.

Why is the first result almost, but not quite, `29`? Because binary floating-point math cannot precisely represent numbers that are "nice" in decimal, such as `0.16`. In binary, this is a repeating fraction that never terminates and as such cannot be precisely represented in finite memory.

So why do we use binary floating-point numbers if they're not accurate? Because the computer has hardware for dealing with them so math is very fast, and they are accurate enough for most purposes. You can use the `Decimal.decimal` class for exact representation of decimal numbers, but it will make your math slower.

Answer (score 0):

it is a Problem of 
try

```
print 25*(1+16.0/100) - 29
```

and you will get a very very Little number smaller than Zero.

maybe you should use round instead or in combination of int

```
print int(round(25*(1+16.0/100)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Casting to an integer in python simply removes the decimal places. To get the rounded integer value you could use

```
return int(round(25.0 * (1 + 16.0/100)))
```

This would return 29.

```
return round(25.0 * (1 + 16.0/100))
```

This would return 29.0 because the value is still represented as a floating point and has not been cast to an integer.